# Why does Numpy operate 0.1M matrix 1000 times is much faster than operate 1M matrix 100 times?

Tags: python, numpy

I found a weird phenomenon that Numpy seems much faster when operating the smaller matrix, even when the total amount of data is identical. Why does this happen?

```py
import time

import numpy as np


def a():
    ts = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        x = np.random.rand(100000, 2).reshape(-1, 2)
        y = np.random.rand(100000)
    te = time.time()
    print(te - ts)


def b():
    ts = time.time()
    for i in range(1000):
        x = np.random.rand(10000, 2).reshape(-1, 2)
        y = np.random.rand(10000)
    te = time.time()
    print(te - ts)


a()
b()
a()
```

```
0.30100059509277344
0.25199460983276367
0.30100131034851074
```

Comment: Cpu caches are likely responsible

Comment: If you keep running a() b() a() b(), I get that sometimes a is faster. Look at my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

They are roughly the same if you do not use the `time` library - which makes sense. Variation in computing function time is huge. Only once is not going to validate that a function is faster (if it is not significantly faster).

```
def a():
    for i in range(100):
        x = np.random.rand(100000, 2).reshape(-1, 2)
        y = np.random.rand(100000)


def b():
    for i in range(1000):
        x = np.random.rand(10000, 2).reshape(-1, 2)
        y = np.random.rand(10000)

%%timeit -n100 -r10
a()
225 ms ± 4.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n100 -r10
b()
224 ms ± 2.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Can't confirm. With your functions, ```%timeit``` still shows ```a()``` to be about 50 to 60 ms slower than ```b()``` on my machine (380 ms vs. 320 ms).

Comment: Again, variation in time matters. Do it for multiple runs and loops like I did. It is roughly the same.

Comment: ```%timeit -n100 -r10 a()```: 397 ms ± 11.6 ms per loop; same for ```b()```: 335 ms ± 10.5 ms

Comment: I see. This is interesting. Nevermind my answer then. Hmmm but why is it different in both computers?

Comment: Good question. Maybe in your tests the difference gets buried in some sort of constant overhead?